# python using random.choice & join() - how to use the created string?

Tags: python, join, tokenize

i am using this code

```
def randomtext(length):
    return ''.join(random.choice(string1) for i in range(length))`
```

to create a "random text" out of

```
string1 = "abcdefg "
```

with the lenght of 20000.

but now i need to use the created text and tokenize it with a whitespace tokenizer.

```
re.split(r"\s+",text)
```

if i use

```
re.split(r"\s+", string1)
```

it is just tokenizing the initial string1 which was the fundation for the random text creation, but the join() function didnt seem to add in all the randomly created words

Comment: Did you call your function? Where?

Comment: what do you mean? if i use re.split(r\s+", randomtext(lenght) its not possible because its no defined string

Comment: btw. you can use `text.split()` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your pbm :

```
def randomtext(length):
    import random
    return ''.join(random.choice(string1) for i in range(length))
string1 = "abcdefg "
text = randomtext(200)
import re
re.split(r"\s+",text)
```

gives me  :

```
['de',
 'b',
 'e',
 'aeaecfebef',
 'bcbaf',
 'fbecfgcbggbcbaeadfdfafcccabddfdfa',
 'ggc',
 'g',
 'cef',
 'bbbffcfbdfgaeg',
 'gabbfccabaedadbgcaa',
 'gaafbdg',
 'bgdaaeeddebced',
 'ge',
 'c',
 'aafg',
 'gcadfaegebfbef',
 'abageegceebecdbacabef',
 'dfcabfg',
 'cdb',
 'eecdf',
 'gfcacd',
 '']
```

Comment: Why the answer when you didn't understood the problem? You should have asked for clarity from the OP as comment :)

Comment: well, showing there is no problem is an answer, no ? maybe you are right, but the comment section is not as clear as the answer part :-/

Comment: ok, i was just too stupid to set "text = randomtext(20000)" so nvm, thanks for your answer, i was going crazy

Comment: If the answer is fine for you, you may click on it to accept it ;)